# How do I connect to a 3rd party ws service in golang as a client with gorilla in golang? Or is it not possible?

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I just want to connect to a trading ws address with gorilla websocket package but all I could find was the server side of the web socket implementation. How do I connect to a ws address and send/receive messages from it. Is there an code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of a Websocket as a direct pipeline of information between a server and a client - and like Unix pipes, information can be both sent and received from both ends.

`gorilla/websocket` works exactly this way. You'll want to take a look [here](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/master/examples/echo/client.go) from lines 29-50 on how to connect to a websocket server and read for messages sent from the server end. In short, to send a message:

```golang
// c *websocket.Conn needs to be initialized from websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial

err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, []byte("Hello, World!"))
```

And to read a message:

```golang
messageType, msg, err := c.ReadMessage()
```

You probably won't need or care about the `messageType` returned from a call to `c.ReadMessage()`, but just in case you do, it's defined in the [Websocket RFC Spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455.html#section-11.8):

```
     |Opcode  | Meaning                             | Reference |
    -+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------|
     | 0      | Continuation Frame                  | RFC 6455  |
    -+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------|
     | 1      | Text Frame                          | RFC 6455  |
    -+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------|
     | 2      | Binary Frame                        | RFC 6455  |
    -+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------|
     | 8      | Connection Close Frame              | RFC 6455  |
    -+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------|
     | 9      | Ping Frame                          | RFC 6455  |
    -+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------|
     | 10     | Pong Frame                          | RFC 6455  |
    -+--------+-------------------------------------+-----------|
```

Comment: Do you think that it is fully implemented in gorilla websocket package? Doyou have any other resources on the topic?

Comment: The gorilla/websocket library "provides a complete and tested implementation of the WebSocket protocol" ( https://github.com/gorilla/websocket#status ). Anything you could feasibly do with something like the JavaScript Websocket can be implemented with this library. I am not the resource on the topic, their docs are. It was pretty easy to find code examples ( https://github.com/gorilla/websocket#documentation ). All you need to do is read up.

Comment: Most go packages nowadays that are worth their salt will also provide a godoc page. https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket